# How to compile Evolution from source

Tags: gnome, compiling, evolution, ubuntu-gnome, source-code

I've been having problems with Evolution the mail client. I've tried purging reinstalling and when I run from the terminal there a "core dump" error.

So I want to try compiling the package.

I know the basics of using make but I need dependencies and is getting nowhere because I can't locate the packages.

This is the output of ./configure

```
    checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether UID '1000' is supported by ustar format... yes
checking whether GID '1000' is supported by ustar format... yes
checking how to create a ustar tar archive... gnutar
checking whether make supports nested variables... (cached) yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for supported compiler flags...  -Wno-deprecated-declarations -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wformat -Wformat-security -Winit-self -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wmissing-noreturn -Wnested-externs -Wpointer-arith -Wredundant-decls -Wundef -Wwrite-strings
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for gcc... (cached) gcc
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... (cached) none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... (cached) yes
checking dependency style of gcc... (cached) gcc3
checking for inline... inline
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... (cached) yes
checking for gawk... (cached) gawk
checking for perl... /usr/bin/perl
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.16... yes
Package gio-2.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gio-2.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'gio-2.0' found
configure: error: glib-compile-schemas not found.
```

Comment: See https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Evolution/Building

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the build requirements for the Ubuntu version of Evolution with a simple:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep evolution
```

If the requirements have changed since then, you might have to manually fulfil some dependencies.

Comment: Compiling with some features disabled....

Comment: e-html-editor-selection.c:7128:1: internal compiler error: in df_ref_record, at df-scan.c:2655
:(

Answer (score 0):

You have :

> No package 'gio-2.0' found

Package `gio` is included in `libgio2.0-cil-dev`. Install it by running :

```
sudo apt-get install libgio2.0-cil-dev
```